# Play the video using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to play the video (Using JUnit) - Day01 of following website. 
http://www.itelearn.com/live-training/security-testing-live-training
What I am trying to achieve is after playing the video I will take a screen shot to prove that video is playing properly. After clicking on Day01 video, it opens in a new window- when I looked at the code I realized that they have used iFrame. I am able to close this video window but not able to play/pause this video.

To close the video I have used code--
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath))).click();

I am new to testing please help me.

Answer (score 2):

So did you switch into the iframe?

Try the following untested Java code, please note that the logic here is simple, you find the iframe element by xpath or css selector, then switch to it, then click. However, automating player may not be that easy and stable. Provide feedback if you can, thanks.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement playerIframe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#sb-player iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(playerIframe);

// make sure you have html5 video loaded, instead of flash
// otherwise Selenium won't find a thing
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg.ytp-cued-icon")).click();
```

To load HTML5 by default, please see [this page](https://www.youtube.com/html5) or load extension [HTML5 Video for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-video-for-youtube/dolajcekhnohkpncmhgledbmndjpblei?hl=en) when starting Selenium.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this code but its not working. Its giving error in line as its return typ eis void.            WebElement playerIframe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#sb-player iframe"))).click();

Comment: Yes, that's just a simple syntax error as I don't have Java environment. Surely you can fix yourself. Just remove the end `click()`, because I copied that line from your original post and forgot the remove.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me and I appreciate that.  I will download HTML5 video player and try this code. In between I tried following code. So now I can see the play button is red in color that means my control/cursor is over that video but when I try to just click its not playing the video.                                 WebElement location= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));//gets Member area xpath
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
     builder.moveToElement(location).build();
     //builder.contextClick();
     builder.contextClick().perform();
     waitTime(10000);

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JavaScriptExecutor. The following approach works for me:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js .executeScript("document.getElementById(\"video\").play()");
```

I was able to play video from https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html and verify Progress field.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-lightbox");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Open a Div in Lightbox')]"));
element.click();
WebElement frameElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wswxQ3mhwqQ']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Play\']")).click();
```

Comment: Could you add explanation what this code does and how it answers original question

Comment: It will open a frame and run video in that frame